# Simple way to check if all required form elements have values

Tags: jquery

I have a page that hosts form generated dynamically by users. I don't know what the fields by type of name but need a way to check is all required fields have values, before I submit the page. I was thinking of running a loop to check for each required element but because some may have multiple fields with the same name I'm not sure I can do something like this:

```
$("[required=required]").each(function() {
   var nm = $(this).attr("name"),
       ok = 0;

   if (nm.val()) {
      ok = 1;
   }
});
```

Comment: It's unclear why you need to do this. With the `required` attribute, the browser will inform the user that they need to fill in the values with nothing more needed on your part.

Comment: I need to do it without using submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // Only for checkbox

   $("input[type='checkbox'][required=required]").each(function() {
           var ok = 0;
     if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
         var ok = 1;
    }
    });

//For checkbox and radio 

    $("input[type='radio'][required=required],input[type='checkbox'][required=required]").each(function() {
           var ok = 0;
     if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
         var ok = 1;
    }
    });

//for textarea
$("textarea[required=required]").each(function() {
           var ok = 0;
     if ($(this).val().length>0 && typeof $(this).val() !="undefined"){ 
         var ok = 1;
    }
    });

// for all type of inputs

 $("[required=required]").each(function() {
           var ok = 0;
// write validation for input tupe text

//write validation for input tupe number

//write validation for textarea

// write validation for select


// write validation for check box

//write validation for radio button

//write validation for any other input 

    });
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe this will look at each element. The reason I was using "name" attribute because of the radio buttons. In that case I need to make sure at least one is checked and they all have the same name.

Comment: Will this work on textarea, text input, radio and select?

Comment: This will for input type checkbox. If you want set it for textarea and radio box then you need to apply same code structure with different selectors and different validation steps. Let me change the code

Comment: I hope this will gives you idea for validating html input tags.